# Creating channel in discord using python

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I started to make a discord bot using python. I want to create a text channel but I got some error.

```
File "C:\Users\playe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\Discord Bots\DC Black Jack Bot\dc_blackjack_bot.py", line 17, in blackjack
    await client.create_channel(client.server, 'This channel is created by ', type=discord.ChannelType.text)
  File "C:\Users\playe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 296, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(msg.format(self.__class__, name))
AttributeError: '<class 'discord.ext.commands.bot.Bot'>' object has no attribute 'server'
```

Here is my code:

```
server = context.message.server
await client.create_channel(
    server, 
    'This channel is created by ' + context.message.author.name,
    type=discord.ChannelType.text)
```

Comment: Are you using async or rewrite version of discord.py? What is `client`? What is `context`? Are you using ext.commands?

Comment: yes, I'm using async. Here is the full function: async def newserver(context):
    server = context.message.server
    await client.create_channel(server, 'This channel is created by ' + context.message.author.name, type=discord.ChannelType.text)

client is my bot

Comment: The error you posted here has been fixed in the code you added. What error are you getting now?

Comment: It's still the same.

Comment: File "C:\Users\playe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 50, in wrapped
    ret = yield from coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\Programming\Python\Discord Bots\DC Black Jack Bot\dc_blackjack_bot.py", line 16, in newserver
    await client.create_channel(server, 'This channel is created by ' + context.message.author.name, type=discord.ChannelType.text)

Comment: File "C:\Users\playe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 2163, in create_channel
    data = yield from self.http.create_channel(server.id, name, str(type), permission_overwrites=perms)
  File "C:\Users\playe\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 196, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: FORBIDDEN (status code: 403): Missing Permissions

Comment: Judging by the code given in your traceback, your error is typographical. It seems like you have written `create_channel(client.server, ...)` not `create_channel(server, ...)`

Comment: As for the 403, make sure your bot has manage channels permission on one of its roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is typographical. Your code does not match the traceback and in fact works as intended. The traceback implies that your code contained

```
client.create_channel(client.server, ...)
```

not

```
client.create_channel(server, ...)
```

as your given code would suggest.
The error here is that client, which is a `<discord.ext.commands.bot.Bot>` does not have a `server` attribute.